# How to get Collision details of 2 objects Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, collision-detection

I am Developing a Game in which I have two object that are: 1> plane and 2>cloud .
I something to happen when they collide.

I have tried the following 2 methods but they were nothing to help:-
1)

```
 if((cloud.getY()==plane.getY())&&(cloud.getX()==plane.getX()))
            {
                plane.reset();
            }
```

and 2)

```
if(((cloud.getY() + cloud.getBitmap().getHeight() / 2)==(plane.getY() + plane.getBitmap().getHeight() / 2))&&((cloud.getX() - cloud.getBitmap().getWidth() / 2)==(plane.getX() - plane.getBitmap().getWidth() / 2)))
        {
            plane.reset();
        }
```

I have initialsed both the plane and cloud with bitmaps in separate classes and the getY() and getX() methods return their co-ordinates in int.

the plane object:-
    plane=new Plane(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.plane), 250, 700);

the cloud object is also same

Someone please help.

Comment: get the center of both objects and then detect collision on the basis of radius or diameter!

Comment: please, provide more details on the objects you are working with, and why those methods you mentioned don't satisfy you?

Comment: I have also tried that but was unable
if you can then please show me some code scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use range in conditions. It may happen that your speed of moving objects is not 1.
    so in that case this condition never satisfy.

```
suppose you have 2 objects then source and dest then condition will be as below:
// use below condition for x
if(source.x >=dest.x && source.x<=(dest.x+dest.width))
// use below condition for y
if(source.y >=dest.y && source.x<=(dest.y+dest.height))

This both conditions are required to check collision.
```